# No Results from ACF Repeater Field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a WordPress site with the ACF repeater field installed. I have followed the video tutorials down to a t and have tried every version of the template code examples on the site but I can't get anything to display at all, nothing.

My repeater field name 'carousel_images' and it has 3 sub fields, 'image', 'headline' and 'text'.

Can anyone help? I just want to display these fields on the front-end on my homepage, which is a static page using the 'front-page.php' template.

**My code:**

```
<?php if(get_field('carousel_images')): ?>
    <div>
        <?php while(has_sub_field('carousel_images')): ?>
            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3><?php the_sub_field('headline'); ?></h3>
                <p><?php the_sub_field('text'); ?></p>
                <a href="#" class="hero-button" data-reveal-id="loginModal">Login <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></a>
                <a href="#" class="hero-button" data-reveal-id="registerModal">Register <span><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></a>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**EDIT 1**
My repeater field was inside of a custom post type so I had to use the WP_Query to display the custom post type before I tried to display the repeater field. Amended working code below.

Thanks again.

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'home_carousel_image'
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>


<!-- WP_Query WordPress loop -->
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php if(get_field('carousel_images')): ?>
        <?php while(has_sub_field('carousel_images')): ?>
        <div>
            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3><?php the_sub_field('headline'); ?></h3>
                <p><?php the_sub_field('text'); ?></p>
                <a href="#" class="hero-button" data-reveal-id="loginModal">Login <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></a>
                <a href="#" class="hero-button" data-reveal-id="registerModal">Register <span><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <!-- Displayed if no posts or pages are available -->
    <p>There are no posts or pages here!</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My repeater field was inside of a custom post type so I had to use the WP_Query to display the custom post type before I tried to display the repeater field. Amended working code below.

Thanks again.

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'home_carousel_image'
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>


<!-- WP_Query WordPress loop -->
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php if(get_field('carousel_images')): ?>
        <?php while(has_sub_field('carousel_images')): ?>
        <div>
            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3><?php the_sub_field('headline'); ?></h3>
                <p><?php the_sub_field('text'); ?></p>
                <a href="#" class="hero-button" data-reveal-id="loginModal">Login <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></a>
                <a href="#" class="hero-button" data-reveal-id="registerModal">Register <span><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <!-- Displayed if no posts or pages are available -->
    <p>There are no posts or pages here!</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your repeater is not correct. A repeater is a row.

```
<?php if (have_rows('carousel_images')): ?>
    <div>
        <?php while (have_rows('carousel_images')): the_row(); ?>
            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3><?php the_sub_field('headline'); ?></h3>
                <p><?php the_sub_field('text'); ?></p>
                <a href="#" class="hero-button" data-reveal-id="loginModal">Login <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></a>
                <a href="#" class="hero-button" data-reveal-id="registerModal">Register <span><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></a>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment but unfortunately this does not work either, there is just nothing displayed where this code is. My repeater field is a custom post type, does that make any difference to anything?

Comment: I have it working now, I had to change my code as the repeater field was inside a custom post type. Thanks.

Comment: You should accept the answer then, or add the answer yourself and accept that (depending on which is true).

Comment: And Stephen, remember in your original post you never mentioned it was inside a CPT.

Comment: Aibrean - Correct, my mistake, we all make them... Thanks for your answer anyway.